# Why magnetic field is zero along the line of velocity of a charged particle?

Tags: magnetic-fields

Why magnetic field of a uniformly moving charged particle is zero along the line of its velocity? I have researched on it on stack exchange and found nothing and therefore posted this question and they said this question donot match their quality standards!

Comment: This question can only be answered when you tell us what it is you take as the starting point, and/or tell us what you would accept as an answer.

Comment: Do you mean "why is the magnetic field _produced/created by_ a moving charged particle zero along the line of its velocity." At least one answer so far has interpreted your question to mean "the external magnetic field can never be parallel to the motion of a charged particle." So your question needs to be more clearly phrased.

Answer (score 0):

If it wasn't zero, magnetic field would not have the symmetry expected from the system state and Maxwell's equations or theory of relativity. Due to such asymmetric field, another (test) charged particle on that line would experience magnetic force in a direction different than the radial one.

Assuming special theory of relativity, this would correspond to a strange force in the frame of the source particle, which cannot be explained as electric force (since electric force is radial and does not depend on velocity of the test particle) and also not as magnetic force, since magnetic field in this frame vanishes.

Thus your idea of source particle having non-vanishing magnetic field on the line of its motion breaks the standard EM theory and special relativity. In principle, nature could have such unexpected behaviour, but in usual electromagnetic phenomena, we do not observe such things and thus the theory is not compatible with them.

Magnetic field can be non-zero on the line of velocity in case the motion of the particle is not uniform. When the velocity direction changes in time, such as when the particle moves in circles, the particle releases propagating EM field which has zero magnetic component on an expanding and curved line in space (a spiral), thus at any single time, magnetic field on the line of the instantaneous velocity need not be zero.

Answer (score -1):

Consider a point along a line on the trajectory of the moving particle and assume for a moment that there was a magnetic field at that point. Let us give the magnetic field a component parallel to the particle velocity (${\bf B_{\parallel}}$) and a component perpendicular (${\bf B}_{\perp}$) to the velocity of the particle.

The magnetic field in another uniformly moving frame of reference is transformed according to the equation (in SI)
$${\bf B'} = {\bf B}_{\parallel} + \gamma\left({\bf B}_\perp - \frac{{\bf v} \times {\bf E}}{c^2}\right)\ , $$
where $\gamma$ is the usual Lorentz factor. This transformation (along with the equivalent one for the E-field) ensure that (i) Maxwell's equations are still valid in the another frame and (ii) the electromagnetic forces exerted on a charged particle are transformed in the correct way according to Special Relativity.

If we now consider the two components of the hypothetical magnetic field generated by our moving charged particle separately and transform them to be in the rest frame of the charged particle; we see that:

(i) ${\bf B_{\parallel}}$ would not be changed at all. This would mean there was a magnetic field component pointing outwards from the static charge. Since there is no B-field due to a static charge, it must be that ${\bf B}_{\parallel}=0$.

(ii) ${\bf B}_\perp$ would just transform to $\gamma {\bf B}_\perp$ in the charge rest-frame, since ${\bf v} \times {\bf E}=0$ along a line from the charge in the direction of the velocity difference between the frames. Since there is no B-field from a static charge it must be that ${\bf B}_\perp = 0$ too.